# Stream to file from class

Tags: java

I am trying to work with file stream and i have a problem.
This is my code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileOperations myFile = new FileOperations("C:\\My_Programs\\eclipse\\MyJavaFiles\\myFile.txt");
    }

    private static class FileOperations {
        String fileName;

        // constructor without argument
        FileOperations() {
            fileName = "default";
        }

        /*
         * constructor with argument
         * argument is assinged into fileName
         * fileName is used to open stream for input and output  
        */
        FileOperations(String argfileName) {
            fileName = argfileName;

            try {
                // open ouput stream
                PrintWriter fileOutput = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));

                // open input stream
                BufferedReader fileInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            } catch (IOException v) {
                System.out.println(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, that if i implement whole *FileOperations* class in main method, it works fine and i can use **fileOutput** and **fileInput** without any problem.
But i wanted to implement those streams in other method and this is where i got stucked.
Why can't i use something like `String fileLine = myFile.fileInput.readLine();` in main method? For me, it looks like those streams are not even opened despite they should be.

I am aware that i didn't close **fileInput** nor **fileOuptu**, i would close it after working with file.

Thank you for all advices and explanations!

Comment: Because it's a local variable, which exists only inside that function.

Comment: So basically, those streams exists only in moment, when instance is initialized and i can use them only in constructor block of code ?

Comment: You seem to be forcing a sort of procedural logic rather than defining a class model that is actually object oriented. The `main()` method should only be used as an entry point to your application, while the rest of the logic should be implemented as the behavior of the classes you define.

Comment: So i should implement all the work with file in class and use main only for creating an instance?

Comment: Keep the `FileOperations` outside main and remove `static`.
Also make `fileOutput` and `fileInput` variables public global if you need it outside